# Replace string in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

when i am trying to replace string value in Azure logic app
it throwing error that you can't give self reference of variable

```
"Set_variable": {
   "inputs": {
     "name": "Images",
     "value": "@replace(variables('Images'), 'cdn.gomasterkey.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/', '~~')"
   },
   "runAfter": {
     "Append_to_array_variable": [
       "Succeeded"
     ]
   },
   "type": "SetVariable"
}
```

[image]

when i save above code i got this error it doesn't allow me to give self reference although i wanna replace from same variable and again put into it.

Comment: Hi Mughal, as I saw George Chen provided a good solution for workaround, I deleted my answer to avoid misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do self reference in logic app, however you could use [workflow functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#workflow-functions) to get the value, then replace it with the string you want.

I use `actions('Initialize_variable').inputs.variables[0].value` to get the variable.

[image]

[image]